# Storyboard template for webapplication

Tags: templates, storyboard, user-story

I am looking out for storyboard widget for axure or powerpoint template which i want to create for a webapplication. Any link would be helpful.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by this question. If a storyboard is just a user journey between various screens then you can just prototype that in Axure using the built-in functionality; just have each screen as a selectable area so when you click it takes you to the next page of the storyboard, just like Powerpoint. I'm guessing this isn't what you're after, so can you expand on what you mean?

Comment: Are you asking about this http://johnnyholland.org/2011/10/storyboarding-ux-part-1-an-introduction/

Comment: @The Question yes i am looking for the same. But i was looking for a sample ux storyboard template..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For PowerPoint, I would recommend Keynotopia's templates, available here: http://keynotopia.com/web-prototyping/

For Axure, I would recommend Axutopia's templates, available here: http://axutopia.com/libraries/axure-web-widgets-library/

I included the web app ones specifically, but they have bundles if you prototype other types of apps. Both come with royalty-free, pixel-perfect widgets that can be used in production.